# How does one rotate a HTML canvas object around a fixed point using mouse action?

Tags: javascript, css, html

For example it may be used in the application of manually adjusting the hands of the clock. I guess it probably involves translating the needle (to make the end point of the needle the centre of rotation) then rotating it, then translating the needle again.

But since the needle listens to the mouse event all the time, the 1st mouse event will be captured. The result is that the needle ends up being translated and not rotated at all. Mouse event is impossible to debug too...

Any idea or code snippets that I can refer to? Using Javascript or CSS to rotate both fine.

Comment: can you show us what you do so far

Comment: mine is rather messy n modified from someone else code... I am still new to javascript n html5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, you will want to calculate the angle between the centre of the clock face (black dot), and the current mouse position (red dot), relative to the Y axis (cardinal north if you imagine a compass).

If I remember my trig correctly, you can calculate this by using the following:

```
var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;

// alter the angle to be relative to Y axis instead of X
angle += 90;
if(angle < 0) { angle = 360 + angle; }
```

In the formula, x and y are the coordinates of the two points, one of which you will know (it is the centre of the clock face), and the other you can get from the mouse move event.

Once you have the angle, you can simply translate to the the centre of the circle, rotate the canvas by the calculated amount, and draw the hand.

**Update:** I created a jsfiddle to illustrate the angle calculation:

http://jsfiddle.net/DAEpy/1/

[image: rotation]

Comment: I copied ur code to a file, but when i load it in the browser, it turns out to be empty. It says "canvas is null" in the error console. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4256111/turnclocktest.html

Comment: Try moving the script tag to the bottom of the page. The canvas element does not technically exist yet when your code runs.

Comment: I see... I encapsulated some initialization codes to start during onload of "body" instead. Btw, ur solution really helps me a lot! Much simpler n easier to understand than codes I found online (which wasn't really what I want either). Thanks!