# Rotate square with mouse drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, rotation, drag

I'm trying to do something like this, but i need some modifications that i don't know how to do..

Example: http://demo.superdit.com/jquery_image_rotate/

But in that example i've got some issues.
After rotating 360º looks like it goes crazy... probably the math of the code...
and i need to rotate the image that i'm clicking on, not only by the center... but any place of the image i click and drag, it rotates on its axis.

Someone have any idea how to mod that code?
Thanks!

ps: Sorry about my english

Comment: Please post your code.  It would be excellent if you could port the functionality to a jsfiddle, too, so others can manipulate it at will.

Comment: Might want to check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873470/how-does-one-rotate-a-html-canvas-object-around-a-fixed-point-using-mouse-action. Uses canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), it supports things like drawing, dragging and rotating images.

Simple example for drawing and dragging an image:
http://jsfiddle.net/8j8HP/1/

Simple example for rotating an image, where the center of rotation is not the center of the image: http://jsfiddle.net/wXctQ/

Now you just have to calculate the angle from the mouse position to the center of the rotation.

Answer (score -1):

Try propeller.js it is a library to rotate HTML elements by mouse or touch  https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Propeller