# How can i get the a direction from this angle? (Need some math help)

Tags: javascript, math, game-physics

I'm trying to make a very simple game. In it I have objects (`Circles`) that have an `xDirection` and a `yDirection`, both of which can range between `-1` to `1`.

I have another object that can be rotated by the user (`Pointer`) atop of the `Circles`. I've achieved this rotation by copying some code I found online that gave me the `angle` of the `Pointer` from the y-axis that runs through the center of the `Circle`. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873470/how-does-one-rotate-a-html-canvas-object-around-a-fixed-point-using-mouse-action)).

Now i'd like the "gameplay" to be a case of the user angling the pointer into the direction he wants the circle to move. If I have this angle, is there a way I can calculate `xDirection` and `yDirection` for the circle?

Really appreciate any help, I know I need to work on my math!
Oh and I'm technically working in javascript, but i'm thinking there's a purely mathematical solution that could be implemented in many languages?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your problem correctly, this should work:

```
x = -sin(angle)
y = -cos(angle)
```

Comment: Gosh i can't believe how simple it should be. Is you answer presuming that angle is in radians or degrees? It nearly works except: im finding that left and right movements work as desired, up and down are reversed and diagonals are going off at right angles. I'll continue to fiddle with it.. (really going to learn some math after this, is this just basic trigonometry?)

Comment: That's up to you. If you're using JS, `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` expect the angle to be in radians.

Comment: Thank you! I eventually realised i had to minus the angle before the calculation and not the result of the calculation.